# giving identity number in dataset c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, identity-column

I have a **sql table** with only **ID** and **Description** columns. **ID** column is `identity primary key` and sql server increases it automatically when I use sql server management studio. I use **C#** project to add data on this table with **disconnected architecture**. I only give Description column value to `dataset` table and I want ID column to increase automatically on the dataset table as sql server does. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2):

you need to implement your own sequence. keep last assigned value in you application or in database. take next id as oldvalue +1 and update old value . Sql server can not help as you are in "disconnected mode"

Answer (score 1):

You could set autoincrement field in your DataTable, but ID generated this way will not be the same as ID generated by SQL Server.

You can use GUID as you ID, if you want to insert ID into database from client, or you can just generate fake ID on the client to have primary key at your DataSet, but not pass this ID as a parameters when you insert new rows into database, so SQL will generate new ID when you do inserting.

Answer (score 0):

if you fetching the Desc from sql table then why not also get the value from ID column?

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you , this is how to add AutoIncrement column to `DataTable`

```
DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.AutoIncrement = true;
column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;

// Add the column to a new DataTable.
DataTable table = new DataTable("table");
table.Columns.Add(column);
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating Primary Keys for disconnected applications and datasources to avoid multiple clients using the same number - use GUIDs instead as they are always going to be unique.